# File selector with textbox showing full path

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

How to show a textbox, and a select file icon, and when select the file, it will display the full path (no fakepath) of the file in the textbox?

`<input type="file">` seems only shows the file name without the full path.

Comment: [The fakepath is a security measure](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#fakepath-srsly). You can't do anything to deal with it.

Comment: That comment should be an answer, because it is *the* answer :)

Comment: @AlvinWong, yes, if you could post it as an answer, that would be great, at least i can accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decision to hide the full path is due to privacy and security issues.

According to the [*working draft* of the HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-input-element-apis.html#dom-input-value), the `value` attribute:

> must return the string `"C:\fakepath\"` followed by the filename of the first file in the list of selected files, if any, or the empty string if the list is empty.

So, there is probably no way to obtain the full path via JavaScript, or any other means other than using a Java or Flash applet. (Both Java and Flash are not standard, so I don't think you would like it). I'd say you best stick to the standard `<input type="file" />` that is supported by most desktop and mobile browsers.

---

Further note: The reason of returning a *fakepath* but not just the filename, according to [WHATWG](http://lists.whatwg.org/htdig.cgi/whatwg-whatwg.org/2009-March/018981.html):

> The original plan was to just have the filename. Unfortunately, it turns out that if you do that, there are certain sites that break, because they expect the path (and they expect a Windows path, no less). This is why Opera and IE8 return a fake path -- not because HTML5 says to do it. In fact I made HTML5 say it because they were doing it.